# oracle apex barcode generation using javascript

Tags: css, oracle, report, oracle-apex, barcode

I have an apex classic report, which has a barcode column. I managed to display code128 barcode format using the below jquery plugin.

http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html and following the below steps,
1. add the following javascript code to the header of the region

```
var bc;
$("[name=bcTarget]").each(function(index) {
bc = $(this).html();
$(this).barcode(bc, "code128", {barWidth:1, barHeight:30}); });
```

2. add the following to the HTML EXPRESSION section of the column

```
<div name="bcTarget" id="bc_#ITEM_BARCODE#" class="barcode" >#ITEM_BARCODE#</div>
```

The issue I have is, I can't change the width of the barcode. The barcode function has a barWidth parameter (int), which I have set to 1, the barcode width is still not short enough.

I tried to change the font size via CSS but no luck.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks a lot